# MySQL: Delete from one table where not in another without using multiple statements

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to clean up a 7.5GiB table in MySQL by executing the following command:

```
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta WHERE comment_id NOT IN  (SELECT comment_id FROM wp_comments);
```

There is no foreign key between the two fields. Because of the size of (the second? both?) tables, attempting to execute this results in the following error:

> Multi-statement transaction required more than 'max_binlog_cache_size'
>   bytes of storage; increase this mysqld variable and try again

The table is huge enough that I can't feasibly raise binlog_cache_size to accommodate this request. Short of dumping the two tables to disk and diffing their contents with a parser offline, is there some way to restructure the query to more-efficiently perform what I need to do?

Some of things I could do (but I wish to choose the correct/smart course of option):

- Create a new table with a foreign key constraint between the two fields and insert into it, then delete the old and rename the new.
- Using a MySQL derived/virtual table to create a view I could export then re-import
- Dump the two tables and compare w/ a parser to generate a list of IDs to delete

Suggestions welcome, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DELETE wcm
FROM wp_commentmeta wcm
LEFT JOIN wp_comments wc ON wc.comment_id = wcm.comment_id
WHERE wc.comment_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: ... and add a foreign key constraint so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I actually ended up piping `mysqldump .... | sed | tail -n +22 | mysql -f` to avoid the memory consumption (at the cost of a much slower process), but that worked.